# Using a list comprehension, insert an incrementing integer into a list of lists that contain strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, insert, list-comprehension

How can I turn this for loop into a list comprehension?

in:

```
docs = [['a'], ['b']]
i=0
for each in docs:
    print(each.insert(0, str(i)))
    i+=1
print(docs)
```

out:

```
[['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you want a new list or mutate the old list:

- [l.insert(0,str(i)) for i,l in enumerate(docs)]
- [l.insert(0,str(i)) or l for i,l in enumerate(docs)]
- [[str(i)]+docs[i] for i in range(len(docs))]

This will mutate the old list, but only as a side effect, the 'returned' list is wrong:

```
>>> x = [['a'],['b']]
>>> [ l.insert(0,str(i)) for i,l in enumerate(x)]
[None, None]
>>> x
[['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b']]
```

This can be fixed:

```
>>> x = [['a'],['b']]
>>> [ l.insert(0,str(i)) or l for i,l in enumerate(x)]
[['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b']]
>>> x
[['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b']]
>>>
```

or one can generate a new list without mutating the old list:

```
>>> y = [['a'],['b']]
>>> [ [str(i)]+y[i] for i in range(len(y))]
[['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b']]
>>> y
[['a'], ['b']]
```

Comment: ah, I did manage to come up with the first one you have there, but I was worried it was doing something adverse to my program. I also observed the immediate result: [None, None], but then saw that x had changed (confused, I asked my question here). I don't think I want that "mutation" hanging around in my program and since simple seems better, I'll go with the third choice setting, y = [[str(i)]+y[i] for i in range(len(y))] so that I don't have unnecessary lists clogging up the RAM - I have millions of lines in actual data set. Thanks.